# AS3 Hamcrest - Assert one array contains all of another

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, unit-testing, hamcrest

I am attempting to use the Hamcrest matchers that come with the Flashbuilder 4.7 environment.  I have 2 arrays, array A and array B.  What I want to do is make sure that all of the members of B are found in A regardless of order.  I'm looking for something that works kind of like this.

```
var a:Array = new Array( 1, 2, 3, 4);
var b:Array = new Array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

//Both arrays contain the same values so this should
//return true
assertThat( a , hasEachAndEveryLastOneInsideOfIt(b));
```

Right now I've tried 'allOf' and 'hasItems' but I'm not quite able to get a grip on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a gist to handle this with a custom hamcrest matcher.

Usage : assertThat( a , arrayExact(b) );

The Matcher class :

https://gist.github.com/jamieowen/5480802

And the shorthand "arrayExact()" function access:

https://gist.github.com/jamieowen/5480819

It should also match 2d arrays as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
assertThat(a, hasItems.apply(null, b))
```

Of course, this checks that all items in `b` are contained in `a`, meaning that `a` can contain other additional values. If you wanted to assert that `a` and `b` also have the same number of values, then `assertEquals(a.length, b.length)` is fine by me.

The trick here is to use `Function.apply()` because `hasItems()` does not expect an array but `...rest` style arguments.

As a side note, `allOf()` is meant to create a list of matchers for the tested value.